# Facebook comment plugin do not display comments in review tab but it display in public?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook comment plugin to moderate comments but for any reasons they are not shown in review tab but I can see those comments in public how I can review comments e.g approve, disapprove any help would be appreciated.

```
        <form class="comment_box" name="comment_box" onsubmit="return false;">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11&appId=My-Id';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<script> window.location.href </script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

and in the  section I am using this

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="My-id" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="DESC" />
<meta property="og:image" content="IMG" />
<meta property="og:type" content="TYPE"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE NAME"/>
```

Comment: Have you checked that your OG meta tags are ok via the Facebook debug tool?

Comment: Yes, OG meta tags are fine, comments appear in public but not in review tab? I don't know why.

Comment: And you do have `data-href` set to the correct URL, same as `og:url`?

Comment: Yes.I can see the comment in public but not in review tab.

Comment: and there is no warning in debugger.